# Posting empty payload - inbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following config.

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="RequestChannel"
    path="/contractName/-/{resource}/**" 
            supported-methods="POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE"
    request-payload-type="java.util.LinkedHashMap"
    error-channel="ErrorChannel"
    id="InboundGateway"  >
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

When posting json to the server the payload is transformed to a LinkedHashMap as expected, however in certain cases I need to post a request that has no payload, when posting an empty payload the conversion fails with bad request. Just wondering if there is a simple/quick workaround in the config where I could tell it to skip the conversion if payload is empty. Currently I need to post "{}" for it to work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The only one way I see is about coding some custom `HttpMessageConverter`. And I guess that you just need to override a bit `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to populate an empty `Map` for empty request body.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to do the trick. I was wondering if there is a better way to create the new message i.e. there is no HttpInputMessageBuilder ?

Comment: No. Because the Messaging doesn't provide the contract for **null** `payload`. And if you are going to initiate your down stream, you should provide some valid payload, even if it is only an empty string or list. So, if it normal for you client to send a null request, your inbound endpoint should treat it as some valid message payload, because it just prohibited by Messaging. I guess that `NullRequestHttpMessageConverter` might do the trick for you, too.